# Windows mousepointer pointing up to the right

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse-cursor

I have a bunch of mousepointers icons that I'm used to seeing in Windows 7:

- Two headed arrow pointing up and down for resizing vertically
- Two headed arrow pointing side to side for resizing horizontally
- Two headed arrow pointing diagonally for resizing both vertically and horizontally
- Blue donut (formerly hourglass) means I'm busy, please wait.
- Hand with an extended finger for clicking on links
- Cross hairs when selecting a rectangular area in a drawing app.
- Arrow pointing up to the left, this is the normal mouse pointer that I see.
- Sometimes I'll see the vertical two headed arrow when my system or app is frozen.

In addition to these, there's occasionally an arrow pointing up to the right.  It seems that I only see it when my system is having performance problems.  Any idea what this arrow is supposed to represent?  I don't recall ever seeing it when everything is normal.

Comment: Have you looked in the Pointers tab of the Mouse control panel to see if it is assigned to anything?

Comment: Do you have an image of it so we know for sure what you are referring to?

Comment: Comparing your description of the regular pointer i would guess you are talking about the "select whole line" pointer (mirror image of the normal mouse cursor) you can get in Outlook or Notepad++ for example, when moving to a certain area left of the line.

Comment: It's not in the mousepointers list in Mouse Properties, it looks pretty much a mirror image the "Normal Select" one.  I only see it very infrequently, but I'll see if I can capture it in a screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the Highlight Current Line cursor. In many text editors it allows you to simple click once and select the entire line of text.

You can see an example of this from Microsoft Word below:

[image: Highlight Current Line in Microsoft Word]

Apologies for the bad quality screenshot, the Problem Steps Recorder doesn't create amazing screenshots and you can't capture the cursor easily any other way.

Comment: That's exactly it!

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me when another Microsoft Application was starting up and I was attempting to click on an email to read.  The mirror image (pointer  pointing to the right) was present while MS Word was coming up.  The pointer flipped backed to the left once MS Word was fully initialized.